Facing Value Error when trying to build BERT model
While building a simple classifier model referred in https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert , I'm getting the below error
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'preprocessing' (type KerasLayer).
A KerasTensor is symbolic: it's a placeholder for a shape an a dtype. It doesn't have any actual numerical value. You cannot convert it to a NumPy array.
Call arguments received by layer 'preprocessing' (type KerasLayer):
• inputs=
• training=None
I'm clueless on how to rectify it. Please help me out here.
def build_classifier_model():
  text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
  preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, name='preprocessing')
  encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
  encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
  outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
  net = outputs['pooled_output']
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None, name='classifier')(net)
  return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)

classifier_model = build_classifier_model()

This is the code I used to build the classifier model.

Hi @Jeshav,The error you're encountering seems to indicate an issue with how you're using the preprocessing layer from TensorFlow Hub. Specifically, it appears that the preprocessing_layer is expecting some input, but it's not receiving it. This might be due to the text_input not being passed to it properly.In the provided code, you're defining a text_input layer, but you're not actually passing any data to it when defining the model.To fix this, you need to ensure that you provide input data to the text_input layer when calling the model.
